# Are Alias' supposed to cascade when grouping?

Tags: google-bigquery

When grouping by a value which is edited in some way and renamed the same value, the updated value, not the original value, appears to cascade down the select statement.  Is this intended behavior?

```
SELECT
  a+1 AS a,
  FIRST(a) AS b
FROM (SELECT 1 AS a),
     (SELECT 2 AS a)
GROUP BY
  a    

-- a | b
-- -----
-- 2 | 2
-- 3 | 3
```

vs

```
SELECT
  a+1 AS a_incremented,
  FIRST(a) AS b
FROM (SELECT 1 AS a),
     (SELECT 2 AS a)
GROUP BY
  a_incremented

-- a_incremented | b     
--       2       | 1
--       3       | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example gives more insight on this

```
SELECT
  a + 1 AS a,
  FIRST(a) AS b,
  FIRST(a + 0) AS b0,
  FIRST(a + 1) AS b1,
  FIRST(a + 2) AS b2
FROM (SELECT 1 AS a),
     (SELECT 2 AS a)
GROUP BY
  a   

a   b   b0  b1  b2   
2   2   1   2   3    
3   3   2   3   4
```

I found rule for myself to get thru this confusion.
If I use overloaded field/alias (in this case `a`) in any expression (like for b0, b1, b2) it (BigQuery) uses original field
If I use that overloaded field/alias by its own (as for b) it uses alias